# updating cell's value in excel file using openpyxl without over writing with python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to update cell in excel file without over writing . I want to insert the new data into the same cell.
the following code as example: the old value is "RAI", I want to add "ANKIT" without over writing. so the cell's value become : "RAI", "ANKIT"

```
# import openpyxl module
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

sheet = wb.active

c1 = sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1)

c1.value = "ANKIT"

wb.save("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\demo.xlsx")
```

Comment: By "add", do you therefore mean "append"?

Comment: @BigBen I means insert the new value  into new line with same cell. I don't know if append can work for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if c1.value:
    c1.value = c1.value + "\n" + "ANKIT"
else:
    c1.value = "\n" + "ANKIT"
```

Comment: I tried . it will throw the following error:
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Apologies, there was a quotation mark missing in the code I posted. Please try again.

Comment: np, another error shown : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: You told us *the old value is "RAI", I want to add "ANKIT"* - this code will work if there is a value in the cell already. If you want to validate to make sure no error is thrown for empty cells, you can do this:

    if c1.value:
        c1.value = c1.value + "\n" + "ANKIT"
    else:
        c1.value = "\n" + "ANKIT"

Comment: (added version with validation to main answer)

Comment: sorry for mis explanation.  it works  now. thanks